# Matching $ at the end

Tags: php, regex

I want to match a $ only at the end.

Why does it does not work:

```
<?php

$reg = '{$$}';
$str= 'helloc$a';
print preg_match($reg,$str);
```

It prints 1 -- matched. But I want it to match for example inputs like abc$ or zzz$ only.

Comment: Escape the first `$`.

Comment: @AgA I've added a documentation link my previous comment ;-)

Comment: @AgA `$` is a metacharacter is regular expressions.  If you want to match a literal `$` you'd need to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is a meta-character in regular expressions and has a special meaning — it asserts the position at the end of a line. When you want to match a literal `$`, you'll need to escape it, i.e. use `\$` instead of `$`:

```
$reg = '{\$$}';
```

As Casmir notes in the comments section below the answer, this pattern will also match when the last `$` is immediately followed by a newline. To prevent this, you can use the following pattern instead:

```
$reg = '{\$$}D';
```

With the `D` modifier set, a dollar metacharacter in the pattern matches only at the end of the given string. If this modifier is not set, `$` also matches immediately before the final character if it is a newline character.

Comment: But doesn't it lose it's special meaning if used in non-anchor places?

Comment: @AgA: Nope. The only way to write a literal `$` is by escaping it. (It behaves as a literal `$` when it's inside a character class too)

Comment: I'm baffled by the downvote; it would be nice for the downvoter to explain why he/she thinks this is an unhelpful and/or incorrect response so I can, perhaps, improve it.

Comment: Pl. don't worry somebody upvoted the wrong answer and down voted yours playing mischief.

Comment: As an aside comment, this pattern will match too if there is a newline immediatly after the last `$`. If you want forbid this case, you can add the `\D` modifier: `{\$$}D`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Thanks for the heads-up. I've updated my answer to reflect this fact.

Answer (score -1):

$ is a special character in PHP. You should add a \ before it . Try this:
$reg = '/\$$/';

Comment: `$reg = '/$\$/';` is incorrect. You need `$reg = '/\$$/';` — note the position of the backslash.